# Howto write a function taking variable number of arguments in F#

Tags: c#, f#

I've got a function in C#, and I'd like to port it (among some other stuff) over to F#, just for the sake of doing it. Unfortunately, I just hit a case for which there seems to be no way to express this in F#: Take this C# function

```
public static T Min<T>(params T[] p) where T : IComparable
{
    T m1 = p[0];

    foreach (T v in p)
    {
        m1 = (m1.CompareTo(v) < 0) ? m1 : v;
    }

    return m1;
}
```

I'd thought this would be pretty easy, but I don't understand how I would specify a variable argument list in F#. I have tried this:

```ml
let rec Min l =
    match l with
    | [] -> 0 // should throw exception here
    | [v] -> v
    | (h::t) -> min h (Min t)
```

but calling that from C# expects a `Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.List`. Is it possible to get it expect a `params T[]`, and if so, how?

Comment: For what its worth, I'd recommend rewriting your function like this: let min l = Seq.reduce min l

Comment: Yep, just seen it, been going through the Seq methods right now (first hit was fold, but reduce is exactly what I'm looking for)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

A params array is simply an array with an attribute, as Jon notes. Add the attribute before the parameter.

```ml
let test ([<ParamArray>] arr : 'a array) = 
    if arr.Length = 0 then invalid_arg "arr"
    // ....
```

You don't need to specify the type:

```ml
let test ([<ParamArray>] arr) = ... // lets type inference do its thing
```

But... pattern matching doesn't work on the array type. You could write an active pattern to help. Basically, you have to decide what's more important: the F# code or the C# code. The same tradeoff will apply as you design higher order functions, use tuples, use discriminated unions, etc. C# can't express most things, and F# doesn't currently support some of the little bits of sugar C# has (Expression Tree writing in the compiler, for example).

Comment: However, in F#, parameter arrays can only be defined in methods. They cannot be used in standalone functions or functions that are defined in modules. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd233213.aspx So let test ([<ParamArray>] arr) doesn't work unfortunately

Comment: What do you mean, doesn't work? open System;;
let test ([<ParamArray>] arr) = ();; -- seems to compile just fine.

Comment: module Test = \n
\t    let test = \n
\t\t        let test' ([<ParamArray>] arr) = () \n
\t\t        test' \n
Attributes are not permitted on 'let' bindings in expressions

Comment: Sure, but they still can be used in "standalone functions or functions that are defined in modules". (The docs are just wrong or confused.)

Comment: `ParamArray` is in the `System` namespace.

Comment: From my testing, let `f ([<System.ParamArray>] args) = args` will compile just fine. However, it does not take a variable number of arguments. It throws a compiler error if you try to pass something that isn't an array. On the other hand `type X() = static member F([<System.ParamArray>] args) = args` can take a variable number of arguments, but is not a proper F# function and can't be composed or curried

Answer (score 7):

Are you wanting to call this method from F# or C#? [This hubFS post](http://cs.hubfs.net/forums/thread/8972.aspx) seems to indicate that F# doesn't support parameter arrays on the calling side, but I suspect if you use a normal type annotation for the parameter to make it an array, and also decorate it with [ParamArrayAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.paramarrayattribute.aspx), you should be able to call it with variable arguments from C#.

Can't say I've seen how to decorate a parameter with attributes in F# yet, but I can hunt around if you want... [This blog post](http://lorgonblog.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!701679AD17B6D310!161.entry) gives a couple of examples, but not at the parameter level.