# How to flatten input of mixed 'T and seq<'T> into single seq<'T>

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

I need a function that could take an arbitrary number of arguments, each could be either of type `'T` or `seq<'T>`. Inside the function I need to process it as a single `seq<'T>` with all inputs combined in the same order as they sere supplied.

The obvious way was to have something like:

```
module Test =
    let flatten ([<ParamArray>] args) =
        let flat = seq {
                for a in args do
                    match box a with
                    | :? int as x -> yield x
                    | :? seq<int> as sq -> 
                        for s in sq do
                            yield s
                    | _ -> failwith "wrong input type"
                }
        flat // this should be seq<int>
```

but I cannot make it work in FSI even with the simplest case

```
let fl = Test.flatten 1;;
  ----------------------^

...: error FS0001: The type 'int' is not compatible with the type 'seq<'a>'
```

What is wrong here and how to get it work as needed? Probably this could be done in some completely different way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd233213.aspx) :

> In F#, parameter arrays can only be defined in methods. They cannot be
>   used in standalone functions or functions that are defined in
>   modules.

So instead of a module, declare a type with a static method.

```
open System
type Test() =
    static member flatten ([<ParamArray>] args: obj[]) =
        let flat = seq {
                for a in args do
                    match box a with
                    | :? int as x -> yield x
                    | :? seq<int> as sq -> 
                        for s in sq do
                            yield s
                    | _ -> failwith "wrong input type"
                }
        flat
```

If you have other let bindings you can still declare a module with the same name.
Also note that in the second guard of the match you can avoid the `for` loop by doing:

```
| :? seq<int> as sq -> yield! sq
```

And `box` is not required.

Comment: Discussed this recently at http://stackoverflow.com/a/674422/801189, actually a module could have such function, only let in expressions couldn't. I still cannot make it work in FSI. Have you tried running this in FSI?

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly. Copy the code to a .fsx, send it to fsi and try in fsi let fl = Test.flatten(1,seq [1;2;3])

Comment: Thanks! Looks like MSDN is right (and I was right in the linked discussion). Now it works, but I still would prefer a module, not a type.

Comment: I personally wouldn't care if I have to put it in a type, from the outside world is the same and modules are compiled to types. When I write functions intended to be consumed from C# normally I use types, so I can use more .NET features like this or overloading.

Comment: I agree! But in my case I am writing a DSL with many compositional functions and writing each time Type.funA(Type.funB(x), Type.funC(y)) instead of funA(funB(x), funC(y)) if ugly. Probably I should dig into computation expressions

Comment: OK, in that case rather than ParamArray I would use just a function accepting a list. So I will call funA [funB [x]; funC [y]]