# How to write a variadic function in F# emulating a similar Haskell solution?

Tags: f#, variadic-functions

How can I (if at all) emulate **variadic functions** (not methods) so that I could write

```
sum 1 2 3
sum 1 2 3 4 5
sum 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
// etc.
```

The code above is just meant as an **example** - obviously if I would have to sum up a list then

```
[ 1; 2 ; 3] |> List.sum
```

is a much better way.

However I am looking for a **structurally similar** solution like [this Haskell solution](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Variadic_function#Haskell)

What is also important is that the *normal* syntax for function calls and parameter values remains the same. So

```
sum 1 2 3
```

vs

```
sum(1, 2, 3)
```

which effectively means that

```
let sum ([<ParamArray>] arr) = ...
```

is not wanted in this specific case.

The motivation for all of this: I am exploring the outer fringes of F#'s type system and syntax. And I am fully aware of that I might have crossed the boundary of what is possible already.

PS: my concrete ideas (which I have not described here) can also be solved completely differently - so I know and so I have done already. 
Therefore my question is not: how can this be solved differently but how can this be solved structurally like Haskell.

PPS: Double Karma-Points if you can make the whole solution recursive.

Comment: See parameter arrays here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233213.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [Howto write a function taking variable number of arguments in F#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/674319/howto-write-a-function-taking-variable-number-of-arguments-in-f)

Comment: @scrwtp: I have extended the question. I hope its even more clear now that this is not a duplicate question. At least not to your link.

Comment: Very interesting question. After your update it's clear that is not a duplicate. I don't understand why was down-voted.

Comment: @robkuz: Fair enough. Seems everyone's having fun with it, so I rest my case.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You said function, not method. So `ParamArray` is not an option.

The Haskell code you linked is based on the inferred result type.

Here's a way to resolve based on the inferred result type in F#:

```
type T = T with
    static member inline ($) (T, r:'t->'t        ) = fun a b     -> a + b
    static member inline ($) (T, r:'t->'t->'t    ) = fun a b c   -> a + b + c
    static member inline ($) (T, r:'t->'t->'t->'t) = fun a b c d -> a + b + c + d

let inline sum (x:'a) :'r = (T $ Unchecked.defaultof<'r>) x

let x:int = sum 2 3 
let y:int = sum 2 3 4
let z:int = sum 2 3 4 5
let d:decimal = sum 2M 3M 4M

let mult3Numbers a b c = a * b * c
let res2 = mult3Numbers 3 (sum 3 4  ) 10
let res3 = mult3Numbers 3 (sum 3 4 5) 10
```

**UPDATE**

The above code doesn't work anymore as from F# 4.1 (see the comments) but here's a better example with a recursive polyvariadic function taking n (unlimited) arguments:

```
type T = T with
    static member        ($) (T, _:int    ) = (+)
    static member        ($) (T, _:decimal) = (+)

let inline sum (i:'a) (x:'a) :'r = (T $ Unchecked.defaultof<'r>) i x

type T with
    static member inline ($) (T, _:'t-> 'rest) = fun (a:'t) -> (+) a >> sum


let x:int = sum 2 3 
let y:int = sum 2 3 4
let z:int = sum 2 3 4 5
let d:decimal = sum 2M 3M 4M

let mult3Numbers a b c = a * b * c
let res2 = mult3Numbers 3 (sum 3 4) (sum 2 2 3 3)
let res3 = mult3Numbers 3 (sum 3 4 5 11 13 20) 10
```

You can also have a look at this [polyvariadic fold](https://gist.github.com/gusty/b6fac370bff36a665d75).

Comment: Not sure why this was down-voted, because it *does* answer the question. Though I suppose this only works for a fixed number of overloads, right? (I wouldn't recommend writing F# in this way, but that's a separate topic.)

Comment: I also don't understand why this has been downvoted. Sofar the best answer AND if I may say so the only one that has read my (initial) question ;-)

Comment: @gustavo: can you make that recursive as well?

Comment: I think that your last edit just killed 1,000,000 kittens. But it's amazing that it can be done.

Comment: @TomasPetricek It also killed my compiler when trying with more than 10 args ;)

Comment: Impressive! - thou I woudnt claim I understand really what is going on.

Comment: This code throws a `TypeInitializationException` when run in Debug build in VS2015. It works in Release build though. I have [reported it to the F# team here](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/865).

Comment: Thanks @abel. I didn't know that but I'm not surprised, I saw more stuff like this that fails in Debug. I've never reported it because was hard to find a small repro, but this case is actually small.

Comment: FYI: in recent versions of F# the issue I mentioned in the previous comment has been resolved and is no longer a problem, this (2nd) pattern compiles and executes find in Debug and Release builds. However, the 1st pattern in this post will raise a "This value is not a function and cannot be applied" error when using `sum`. Reported here: https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/5214

Comment: Yes, that was known regression, I will add more info in the issue.

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned in the comments, you can use the `ParamArray` attribute in F# and this will let you call the function with multiple parameters - although you'll have to use the .NET notation and write `sum(1,2,3,4,5,6)`.

That said, I probably wouldn't do this in practice. If you're writing a function that takes an input consisting of an unknown number of values, then using a list is likely a better design:

```
List.sum [1; 2; 3 ]
List.sum [1; 2; 3; 4; 5 ]
List.sum [1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7 ]
```

This is only a few more characters and it better models the problem that you're solving - at least, based on the toy example you posted here.

It is hard to give a good answer without knowing what is the problem that you are actually solving. But in general, I think taking a list is a good F#-friendly default. Using `ParamArray` is useful in some cases and for C# interop.

Comment: @robkuz As "exploring the boundaries of F# type system", this makes good sense. Though I still think it is important to say that nobody should really do this in practice :-). This is especially the case with questions asking "how can I do XYZ from Haskell in F#" because they often point people in a wrong direction (blindly using techniques from one language in another language is never a good idea). Of course, pure out-of-the-curiosity kind of questions are an exception!