# Function with an arbitrary number of arguments in F#

Tags: recursion, f#, type-inference

I want to write a function that will take an arbitrary number of (curried) arguments and simply print them out (or perform some other unspecified action with them). Here is what I have come up with:

```
let print arg =
    let rec print args arg =
        if not (FSharpType.IsFunction(typeof<'t>)) then
            printfn "%A" args
            Unchecked.defaultof<'t>
        else
            print (box arg::args)
    print []
```

When I try to compile this I get the error `The resulting type would be infinite when unifying ''t' and ''a -> 't`.

I know I could just pass the arguments as a list, but I am trying to develop an API of sorts where this would be a useful idiom to have.

Is there some clever compiler trick to make such a function possible in F# or is it a lost cause?

Comment: There are some ways to encode variadic functions in F# but the compiler trick is really really tricky. See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28243963/how-to-write-a-variadic-functios-in-f-emulating-a-similar-haskell-solution)

Comment: well silly me - the obvious workaround is collecting all interesting input types into an ADT and just use a list over this type I guess

Comment: Thanks Gustavo, that answer does what I wanted.  I'm voting to close this as a duplicate.  I probably should have searched more before asking but was on a really shoddy connection when I asked it. :-)

Comment: If you wanted to be silly and don't mind super slow compile times you could use something like the [HList here](http://www.fssnip.net/pu).

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the two branches of the inner `print` want to return different types: the "then" part wants to return `'t`, but the "else" part wants to return `'a -> 't`, where `'t` is necessarily the same in both branches. That is, your function tries to return either its own return type or a function from another type to its own return type. Such combined return type would, indeed, be infinite, which is in perfect accordance with what you set out to do - namely, create a function with infinite number of arguments. Though I do not know how to formally prove it, I would say this is indeed impossible.

If your goal is to simply create a list of boxed values, you could get away with defining a few infix operators.

```
let (<+>) a b = a @ [(box b)]
let (<&>) a b = [(box a); (box b)]

let xs = 5 <&> "abc" <+> 3.0 <+> None <+> true
>> val xs : obj list = [5; "abc"; 3.0; null; true]
```

Alternatively, with carefully chosen operator precedence, you can apply a function (but then you'll need a terminator):

```
let (^>) a b = (box a)::b
let (<&>) f xs = f xs
let print xs = sprintf "%A" xs

let xs = print <&> 5 ^> "abc" ^> 3.0 ^> None ^> true ^> []
>> val xs : string = "[5; "abc"; 3.0; null; true]"
```