# In F#, can two functions with different arity and return types share a name?

Tags: types, f#, overloading

In F#, can two functions with different arity and return types share a name?

For example, with 2 arguments, `f` returns an `int`:

```
let f (x:int) (y:int) : int = x + y
```

But with 3 arguments, `f` returns a `bool`:

```
let f (x:bool) (y:bool) (z:bool) : bool = x & y & z
```

It seems like the return type *should* be inferable by the number of arguments given, but I get the compilation error:

> Duplicate definition of value 'f'

Is this a limitation of F#?

Comment: You can do this with members, but note that `f 1` has an ambiguous type which could be a problem

Comment: *Added explicit types to all arguments*

Comment: this is an limitation - functions in modules need to have different names

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's analyse both features:

- Different return type:

This is not trivial in F# as in other functional languages, but it's possible and at some point they make sense. Typical examples are the math operators, they return different types based on the input parameter types, so in the end what you have is a single generic function. This in not the same idea as method overloading where you have many methods which share the name.

- Different number of arguments:

This is even less trivial, also in other functional languages with automatic currying, because it will conflict with that feature. Still there are some (few) cases where they might make sense, [here's an example coming from Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28243963/how-to-write-a-variadic-functios-in-f-emulating-a-similar-haskell-solution/28244413#28244413).

- Both at the same time:

This makes practically no sense, the idea behind overloaded functions is to have a relationship between the types of the input (and maybe also the output) arguments of the different overloads which would feel as a single generic function.
So in this case it resemble more .NET method overloading which by the way is a feature supported in F#.

Finally, using some hacks you can encode your example in F#:

```
let f (x:int) (y:int) : int = x + y
let g (x:bool) (y:bool) (z:bool) : bool = x & y & z

type T = T with
    static member ($) (T, x) = fun y   -> f x y
    static member ($) (T, x) = fun y z -> g x y z

let inline myFunc x y = (T $ x) y

let result1 = myFunc 3 5
let result2 = myFunc true false true
```

But again, I don't think it's a good idea.

Comment: Yes I agree that it is not a good idea, I just wanted to know if it is possible.