# How to leverage power of TextWriterFormat for printfn style in combination with ConditionalAttribute which requires unit result

Tags: f#, printf, partial-application, debug-build, conditional-attribute

I set myself to creating a trace function that behaves like `sprintf` or `printfn`, but is disabled (JIT removes it on call site) for Release builds by using the [`ConditionalAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28System.Diagnostics.ConditionalAttribute.%23ctor%29;k%28SolutionItemsProject%29;k%28DevLang-fsharp%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5%29&rd=true).

**Result so far: I don't think it is possible.**

The problem centers around the fact that when you use the `Conditional("DEBUG")` attribute, the function must return unit result. "Normal" arguments work as they should and the method is properly decorated (EDIT: *decorated*, yes, but curryable members are *not erased*, see [discussion](https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/846), must use tuple-form instead):

```
type Trace() =    
    [<Conditional("DEBUG")>]
    static member inline trace msg b = (msg, b) |> ignore

// using it, x is unit
let x = Trace.trace "test" "foo"
```

(note that, without the `ignore`, this won't compile because of the Conditional attribute)

But as soon as I try any variant of the `Printf.TextWriterFormat<'T>`, it fails and I don't see a way around it:

```
type Trace() =
    [<Conditional("DEBUG")>]
    static member inline trace msg = printfn msg    // inline or not doesn't matter

    // using it, x is unit
    let x = Trace.trace "hello: %s" "foobar"
```

This works without the attribute, but *with* the attribute, it will raise:

> This expression was expected to have type
>          `unit`
>   but here has type
>          `string -> unit`

The error is specifically underlining `Trace.trace "hello: %s"`. So it looks like the compiler not recognizing that the whole of the expression results in a `unit`, and raises the error because it internally creates a wrapper function that returns `string -> unit`, which is not allowed by the rules of the `ConditionalAttribute`.

When I try to fix it by explicitly specifying `:unit` on the function return type, or `printfn msg |> ignore` as the body, then I lose the ability to use the text writer format string with type safety, in fact, it won't recognize the second argument on the call-site at all anymore.

So, while the whole of the function signature obeys CLR's rules, it seems that the inline functions that F# creates do not, at least not in this specific case.

I have tried variants, including `kprintf`, `sprintf` to see if that helped, but all to no avail.

Any ideas? Or is this one of those situations where you try to lay out a carpet and once you have it properly smoothed in one corner, it bubbles up in the other corner, and vice versa, i.e. it never fits?

---

PS: in case you are wondering *why* I want it: just trying to create a convenience function that behaves like existing Trace, but with some other functionality going on under the hood. What I currently have works, but it just takes a string, not a statically type checked arguments, so it forces users to write something like:

```
(sprintf "Hello %s" >> Trace.trace) "foobar"
```

Comment: I wonder if you could do this with an operator?

Comment: @JohnPalmer: any idea how? Operators, afaik, take one or two arguments, not a variable amount of arguments. What I find strange, rethinking my post, is that (1) forcing `unit` on the signature disables formatting arguments, even though it already returns unit, and that (2) returning unit after the `printfn` _also_ cancels the ability to use formatting arguments... I understand why, but I don't understand why...;)

Comment: The operator idea would be to write a bunch of overrides with a different number of arguments.  The problem is that the return type of `printfn` is very weird and depends on the format string

Comment: @JohnPalmer, I'm not quite sure how that would help making it work with the `ConditionalAttribute`, but if you have a prototypical idea that shows what you're heading to, by all means, go ahead and add an answer ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An overloading based version.

You might want some more overloads

```
#if DEBUG
type Log() =
    static member inline log(x) = printfn x
    static member inline log(x,y) = printfn x y
#else
type Log =
    static member inline log(x) = ()
    static member inline log(x,y) = ()
#end
```

### update:

So this works:

```
open System.Diagnostics
type Log() =
    [<Conditional("DEBUG")>]  
    static member log(x) = printfn x
    [<Conditional("DEBUG")>]
    static member log(x,y) = printfn x y
```

you need to switch to the tuple form to allow for overloading and use tuple form as curried things can't be overloaded

Comment: I initially thought the operator trickery would be required but it wasn't needed.  You might actually be able to mark these with the conditional anyway.

Comment: Ah, now I get how it works, and it works! The type inference works correctly. The call site is completely removed by JIT, all's good! (Strange, because I thought I experimented with tuples, but apparently never tried the simple approach ;). This is quite easily extensible and my previous comment to that extend is superfluous, you just need a variant for each number of arguments (and you must tuple the args).

Comment: Any idea _why_ this works with tuples and not with curried arguments?

Comment: You can't overload curried functions

Comment: I understand, but that's not my point, I mean, where are the curried arguments in my original post? I.e. `log x = printfn x`. Or you mean that, as a result of the StringWriterFormat etc, I end up having curried arguments anyway? But in the OP I wasn't overloading them, I just had one definition...

Comment: @Abel As a side note, it is possible to encode polyvariadic functions (with curried arguments) in F# but it's very hacky. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28243963/how-to-write-a-variadic-function-in-f-emulating-a-similar-haskell-solution/28244413#28244413).

Comment: @Abel - check what the type of `printfn "test"` and `printfn "%s"` are.

Comment: I understand that `printfn "%s"` creates a function that takes a string. But the thing is, if I decorate `fn a b = a + b |> ignore` with `Conditional`, there is no problem, but when I decorate `fn a b = printfn "s%s" a b` then it fails, though both have unit return type. I don't see the difference. The second one, when assigned to a variable `let x = fn "x" "s"` will show `x` having unit. But F# will complain and won't accept it with `Conditional`.