# Is recursive partial function application possible in F#?

Tags: recursion, f#

I am working with the function 2x^2+y^2, defined in my code as:

`fx = fun x y -> (2 * (pown x 2)) + (pown y 2)`

and I was wondering if it was possible to apply the x and y components recursively?

Currently, if I do, say,

```
let f1 = fx 0.0 //<fun:it@9-2>
let f2 = f1 2.0 //4.0
```

then this works as expected. However, if I were to give my function `a` and `b` parameters to indicate some interval, intellisense throws a fit.

```
let ab = [0.0; 2.0]

let result =
    let rec getres fn lst =
        match lst with
        | hd :: tl -> 
            let f1 = fn hd
            getres f1 tl   // <- error here
        | [] -> fn
    getres fx ab
```

then intellisense on `f1` gives me an error:

```
Type mismatch. Expecting a 
  "a -> 'b' 
but given a 
  "b'. 
The types "a' and "b -> 'a' cannot be unified
```

I want to be able to recursively apply any number of parameters from a list of parameters (e.g. my `ab` list in the example above) to a function that I supply to my expression, in the form of `fun x1 x2 x3 … xn -> x1 + x2 + x3 + … + xn`. Is this possible?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674319/howto-write-a-function-taking-variable-number-of-arguments-in-f?

Comment: That isn’t at all what I’m trying to do. The function, e.g. fx defined above, takes 2 parameters, which I have supplied in a list of 2 elements. I want to apply them recursively, so that the intermediate, or accumulator if you will, is a function of partial application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may need to specify a signature for the function argument of `getres`. Based on the error message the compiler is inferring that `fn` takes a single argument and returns a result. So on the error line `f1` is not a function but a value. Ie. there is no currying happening.

But that won't handle the final case where you want to execute the function rather than performing partial application. You may need an extra level of indirection to handle this. (In other .NET languages one would need to use reflection for this – which allows a function to be called passing an array of parameters – it may not be possible in a strongly typed .NET language to handle this without reflection.)

---

Additional (to summarise the comments below):

Consider the required signature of `getres`. If `fn` is a function of two arguments (ie. `'a -> 'a -> 'b`) then `getres` has a signature:

```
('a -> 'a -> 'b) -> list 'a -> ('a -> 'b`)
```

for the first call.

But when that instance of `getres` makes its recursive call it needs to be a function taking a single argument, ie. its signature needs to be:

```
('a -> 'b) -> list 'a -> 'b`
```

This is not possible with a single F# function.

It is possible with a .NET function (ie. a class member), but only if each "level" is separately written (ie. hard coding the maximum number of arguments). (Compare how `System.Func<T1, TRes>`, `System.Func<T1, T2, TRes>` are defined in the .NET runtime.)

(This is the kind of thing that dynamic languages can easily handle, but strongly typed languages need a very sophisticated type system underlying it to achieve.)

Comment: I just don’t understand why the type inference can’t infer that (‘a -> ‘a -> ‘a) => (‘a -> ‘a) => ‘a recursively. It works fine if I just do it explicitly. Specifying a signature would mean that I am limited to only giving it functions with that signature, in which case there would be no point in trying to loop over my list of parameters to partially apply each element.

Comment: Why can't the type interference handle this is a question for the F# developers. But the function of `(‘a -> ‘a -> ‘a) => (‘a -> ‘a) => ‘a ` can't be inferred here  because these is nothing to determine that in the final case `[] -> ...` that the result is the same as a member type of the input list.

Comment: Finally I think you're problem is limited by .NET only supporting functions of a variable number of args in one way (and this isn't it).  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/674422/67392 on creating functions with a variable number of args in F#.

Comment: See, I don’t think that’s necessary applicable because I’m not creating functions with variable args. If I have a function `fun x y z -> x + y + z` then it takes 3 arguments. F# is perfectly happy with me partially applying a single arg to the function, and then passing that function to another function that applies another arg, etc. It just won’t let me do it recursively.

Comment: Summary: in F# you can't specify a function that can be called taking a function argument without specifying what those arguments (and return type), even if that specification is done by type inference. But here you want the same function to handle `(`a -> `b) -> (() -> `b)` and `(`a -> `a -> `b) -> (`a-> `b)` and … Essentially: what is the signature of `getres`?

Comment: On second thought, I guess it must be that the parameter of the recursive function to which I am feeding the partially applied function has a signature that is inferred down from the very first recursion, and the partially applied function of course doesn’t have that signature?

Comment: Yeah, you’re right. I guess I figured that the machinery that allows for partial application would have some capacity to pass the function around more freely and that I could avoid static method overloads.